# How can I do a bitwise-AND operation in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, boolean, bitwise-operators

I want to perform a bitwise-AND operation in VB.NET, taking a Short (16-bit) variable and ANDing it with '0000000011111111' (thereby retaining only the least-significant byte / 8 least-significant bits).

How can I do it?

Comment: Are you doing string concatenation or IF conditions?

Comment: can you give psudo code of what you atempting?

Comment: dim a as short ..... dim b as byte = doing and with a.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

0000000011111111 represented as a VB hex literal is &HFF (or &H00FF if you want to be explicit), and the ordinary AND operator [*is* actually a bitwise operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973672/3973820#3973820).  So to mask off the top byte of a Short you'd write:

```
shortVal = shortVal AND &HFF
```

For more creative ways of getting a binary constant into VB, see: [VB.NET Assigning a binary constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660014/vb-net-assigning-a-binary-constant)

Comment: can I use &H00FF... what is difference with &HFF and &H00ff

Comment: @Barun: the leading 0s are superfluous. Use 'em if you want to... It makes no difference.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `And` operator, and write the literal in hexadecimal (easy conversion from binary):

```
theShort = theShort And &h00ff
```

If what you are actually trying to do is to divide the short into bytes, there is [a built in method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk3sts66.aspx) for that:

```
Dim bytes As Byte() = BitConverter.GetBytes(theShort)
```

Now you have an array with two bytes.

Answer (score -4):

```
result = YourVar AND cshort('0000000011111111')
```

Comment: Strings are delimited with quotation marks not apostrophes. The CShort function doesn't assume binary as base, but decimal, so trying to convert that string causes an overflow.