# What is this logic? [long]=([long] And [long]) or [Long]

Tags: vb.net, vba, logic, logical-operators

I apologize if this is a very basic logic questions, but I saw some code in an example and I'm not understanding the logic structure, so I was hoping someone could explain it to me.

In my examples I'm using `[Long]` simply as a representation for any Long data type object

---

The example looks like this:
NOTE:  wHi, wLow, LoLo, HiLo, LoHI, and HiHI are all long variables.

```
    If (wHi And &H8000&) Then
        MAKELONG = (((wHi And &H7FFF&) * 65536) Or (wLow And &HFFFF&)) Or &H80000000
    Else
        MAKELONG = LoLO Or (&H10000 * LoHI)
        'MAKELONG = ((wHi * 65535) + wLow)
    End If
```

I'm not sure what condition is being tested here: `if [long] and [long] then` and `if [long] or [long] then`

I also don't understand the return logic, e.g.:  `[LONG] = ([LONG] And [LONG]) or [LONG]`

---

I tried playing in the immediate window and that did not shed any light on it for me as I did not see any obvious pattern:

```
?1 or 10
 11 
?2 or 10
 10 
?3 or 10
 11 
?4 or 10
 14 
? 1 and 10
 0 
?2 and 10
 2 
?3 and 10
 2 
?4 and 10
 0 
?5 and 10
 0
```

Comment: it's bit-masking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046457/how-can-i-do-a-bitwise-and-operation-in-vb-net

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra

Comment: Turn `Option Strict On` and you will see that you are getting an error.  It makes no sense to use a Long value in an If statement which expects a Boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's bit masking. e.g. With your test values:

```
    ?1 or 10 -> 11

      00000001 = binary for 1
      00001010 = binary for 10
   OR --------
      00001011 = binary for 11
```

Comment: I actually found the Wikipedia article for bit masking and bitwise operations pretty informative.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation